# How to test a custom Jasmine matcher?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine2.0

I created some custom matchers for Jasmine 2.x for which I want to create specs.
Most programmers test their matchers by just applying them in a test an verify if the outcode is positive.

For example the `.toEqual` 'custom' matcher:

```js
it('should test if two objects are equal', function () {
  expect({}).toEqual({}); // Passing
});
```

However, I want to test the matcher also for failing cases and I want to test the messages they produce when the matcher fails, for example in this way.

```js
// Jasmine 2.x
it('should test if two objects are equal', function () {
  expect(matcher.compare(1, 1)).toEqual({
    pass: true,
    message: 'Expected 1 not to equal 1' // Message is for when you use .not with the matcher 
  });
  expect(matcher.compare(1, 2)).toEqual({
    pass: false,
    message: 'Expected 1 to equal 2'
  });
});
```

The variable `matcher` in the code examples is the matcher function that I added using `jasmine.addMatchers({ toEqual: matcher })`.

Since I want not to polute global space I have no idea how to have the matcher available in my specs. The default jasmine matchers are in `jasmine.matchers` and they are added to [their spec](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/spec/core/matchers/toEqualSpec.js) via some `$j` object.

So the main question actually is: where are my custom matchers stored when I add them to Jasmine? Can I retrieve them for the specs or are they hidden in a closure?

#### Edit

it seems like `addMatchers` is calling `env.addMatchers`, which pushes the matchers to `runnableResources[currentRunnable().id].customMatchers`. RunnableResources is a closure...

Comment: I see that you have since created a framework for testing custom matchers : https://github.com/fvanwijk/testception  -- looks interesting!

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks. This question actually was posted here because I was working on testception :). Too bad that nobody answered it but it rewarded me the tumbleweed badge. I think I have to so something with modules (ES6/requirejs)